# overusing ".present?" in rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a question about process if i could be doing this a better way. I'm working on a rails app and i run into page errors when certian elements are not present. For example here is my show action

```
def show 
    @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:article_slug])
    @section_slug = Section.find_by_id(@article.section_id).slug if @article.section_id.present?
    @issue_slug = Issue.find_by_id(@article.issue_id).slug if @article.issue_id.present?
    @next_article = @article.next_article if @article.next_article.present?
    @prev_article = @article.prev_article if @article.prev_article.present?
    @article_author = Author.find_by_id(@article.author_id)

    render :layout => 'magazine'
    session[:return_to] = request.referer
    #if request.path != article_path(@article)
     #return redirect_to @article, :status => :moved_permanently
    #end
  end
```

Should i be using .present? as much as i am? is there something better that will make pages not fail so completely if an element is not present? Just trying to learn rails in a way that will lead to better code.

Comment: For cases where you genuinely need `y = x if x.present?`, check out the [presence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) convenience method. I'd listen to Carl Zulauf's advice about minimising instance variables in your controllers though. If your models are well designed, it's rarely necessary to have more than one or two (RubyMine will actually give you warnings about this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, why are you not using relations? If `Article` already has `section_id` then you should be getting to the `Section` using `@article.section`. `belongs_to :section` should be in your `Article` model.

The above is true for `Issue` and `Author` as well.

In answer to your question: No, you should not be using `.present?` as much as you are.

Here how I would code this action:

```
def show 
  @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:article_slug])
  @section_slug = @article.section.try(:slug)
  @issue_slug   = @article.issue.try(:slug)
  @next_article = @article.next_article
  @prev_article = @article.prev_article
  @author       = @article.author

  render :layout => 'magazine'
  session[:return_to] = request.referer
end
```

There is no reason for `@prev_article = @article.prev_article if @article.prev_article.present?`. If your views depend on `@prev_article` they will see a nil value with or without the `if @article.prev_article.present?`. Your view is going to have to do `.present?` or similar anyways.

I might actually do away with all but `@article` here and have my views ask the article for its `author`,  `next_article`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think so you need to do only:

```
@next_article = @article.next_article
@prev_article = @article.prev_article
```

If next_article is not present then it will be nil so with present condition and without present condition the value of @next_article and @prev_article will be nil

Answer (score 0):

welcome to RoR

```
if @article.prev_article.present?
```

is the same as

```
if @article.prev_article
```

and

```
@article_author = Author.find_by_id(@article.author_id)
```

looks like you are missing out on a belongs_to relationship. If in your model you define as follows:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles
end
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :author
end
```

Then you can simply call

```
@article.author
```

to retrive the author object. Please do the same for section and issue.

When you want to query a database using ids, ActiveRecord allows you to do this:

```
@user = User.find(1)
```

It looks like you are trying to paginate articles. Give the Kaminari Gem (https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) and Will_Paginate Gem(https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) a go, they come quite well built and maintained.

```
@issue_slug = Issue.find_by_id(@article.issue_id).slug if @article.issue_id.present?
```

In order to not error out when calling a method, the try method is apt.

```
@article.section.try(:slug)
```

Comment: yeah i'd like to use will_paginate but i'm attempting to do something complicated, having a next and prev button that only go to articles within an issue. I'll look at it though to see if i can make things simpler. Thanks for the comment!